# Rails - Form_tag for custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a controller `games` and a method:

```
def index

@games = Game.all

end

def set_game

@current_game = Game.find(params[:set_game])

end
```

In my view I have:

```
<%= form_tag("/games") do %>
<% @games.each do |g| %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:game_id, g.id) %>
<%= label_tag(:game_name, g.name) %><br>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Confirm" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  resources :games

  match 'games', :to => 'game#index'
```

How can I make this form work for my `set_game` method?

Thanks.

Comment: More information is going to be needed.  Also, your form is incorrectly structured.  The label does not match an input.

Comment: I edited with more info. If you need anything else tell me.

Comment: "How can I make this form work for my set_game method?" - it's not very clear to me what you really want to achieve and what exactly do you want to do with the set_game action. Can you please provide more information what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag(set_game_games_path) do %>
 ...
<% end %>

#routes.rb
resources :games do
  collection do
    get '/set_game', :as => :set_game
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an example of a custom route:

```
  match "customroute" => "controller#action", :as => "customroutename"
```

This can be then accessed with "customroutename_url" in your views. If you want to create a custom route for your set_game action, for example, it would be

```
  match "setgame" => "games#set_game", :as => "setgame"
```

Then you can do

```
<%= form_tag setgame_url %>
...
<% end %>
```

You can read more about custom routes here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes